# How can I read a byte[] out of the database and convert it to an image?

Tags: c#, image, arrays

I have a stored procedure that return a varbinary(max) type data. I want to convert that data into an Image.

But I have problems with this line:

```
public Image CargarAvatar(string login)
        {
            System.Object[] Args = new System.Object[1];
            Args[0] = login;

            DataTable X = new DataTable();
            X = TraerDataTable("sp_CargarAvatarUsuario", Args);

            byte[] ImagemByte = Convert.to (X.Rows[0][0].ToString());


            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }
```

Please help! :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A varbinary field is returned as a byte array, so you only need to cast it:

```
byte[] ImagemByte = (byte[])X.Rows[0][0];
```

Then you use the array to create the memory stream:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImagemByte);
```

Comment: After endless efforts, all I had to was pass in the byte array into the stream. +1!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about converting an Int to a byte[] in this case, as I don't see an int anywhere. It's certainly possible to do, I just don't see an application in this case.

You had two real problems. One was creating the byte[], which obviously you know as it wouldn't compile. The second was getting those bytes into the stream.

```
public Image CargarAvatar(string login)
{
    System.Object[] Args = new System.Object[1];
    Args[0] = login;

    DataTable X = TraerDataTable("sp_CargarAvatarUsuario", Args); // No need to create a new DataTable and overwrite it with the return value of TraerDataTable. One assignment will do.

    byte[] ImagemByte = (byte[])X.Rows[0][0]; // If this is an Image in the database, then this is already a byte[] here and just needs to be casted like so.             

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImagemByte); // You need to pass the existing byte[] into the constructor of the stream so that it goes against the correct data
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

    return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create the image from an empty memory stream. Pass the byte array as a parameter to the MemoryStream constructor :

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImagemByte);
```

Answer (score 0):

this for convert image to byte array, at it can be inserted into database as it's:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(BitmapImage myimage)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myimage);
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myimage.PixelWidth, myimage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        return imageBytes;
    }
```

and this for back way:

```
public static BitmapImage ByteArraytoBitmap(Byte[] byteArray)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        return bitmapImage;
    }
```